# How do i output Custom Classes having lists etc data structure from a Map Program in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop and Map Reduce Programming. I have a dataset which contains Ratings about movies from 943 users. Each user has rated up to 20 movies. Now I want the output of my Mapper to be the User Id and a custom class which will have two lists for Movie (movie ids that the user rated) and the Ratings (Ratings for each Movie). But I am unsure how to output these values from the Map method in such a scenario. Code snippets Below:-

```
public class UserRatings implements WritableComparable{
private List<String> movieId;
private List<String> movieRatings;
public List<String> getMovieRatings() {
    return movieRatings;
}

public void setMovieRatings(List<String> movieRatings) {
    this.movieRatings = movieRatings;
}

public List<String> getMovieId() {
    return movieId;
}

public void setMovieId(List<String> movieId) {
    this.movieId = movieId;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput dataOutput) throws IOException {
    dataOutput.write
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput dataInput) throws IOException {

}
```

}

ANd here is the Map Method

```
public class GenreMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,IntWritable> {

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
   // Logic for parsing the file and exracting the data. Can be ignored...
    String[] input = value.toString().split("\t");
    Map<String,UserRatings> mapData = new HashMap<String,UserRatings>();
    for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<String>();
        UserRatings userRatings = new UserRatings();
        tempList.add(input[3]);
        List<String> tempMovieId = new ArrayList<String>();
        tempMovieId.add(input[1]);
        for(int j=4;j<input.length;j++){
            if(input[i].contentEquals(input[j])){
                   tempMovieId.add(input[j+1]);
                   tempList.add(input[j+3]);
                    j = j+4;
            }

        }
        userRatings.setMovieId(tempMovieId);
        userRatings.setMovieRatings(tempList);
        mapData.put(input[i],userRatings);
    }
   // context.write();

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I think you're missing the point of the mapper function. The mapper should not emit a list on it's output. The keypoint of the mapper is to produce a tuple that the reducer will catch and regarding the key make the necessary calculations to produce a good output, given this the output format of mapper should be as simple as possible.

In this case, I think the right approach would be to emit on the mapper a key value pair of:

> user_id, custom_class

The custom class must have a movie_id and a rating only and not a list. To be more specific I would need to know what do you want for the end result of this map reduce cicle. Please note that if you need you can run a second map reduce on the results of the first.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [Text](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/Text.html) and [MapWritable](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/MapWritable.html) as the key value pair for your mapper class.

Here User id will be the **key** (Text) and the Mapwritable composed from the movie id and rating of the user will we the **value** object.

The Mapwritable value object should be composed with the MovieId as key and user rating as the value.

Consider this example code snippet,

```
MapWritable result=new MapWritable();
result.put(new Text("movie1") , new Text("user1_movie1_rating"));
result.put(new Text("movie2") , new Text("user1_movie2_rating"));

Text key = new Text("user_1_id");

context.write(key, result);
```

Hope this helps :) ..